# Select value via jquery using bootstrap-combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I am using [Bootstrap-Combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) and I would like to select the right value via jquery, I use a "returning person" button to select a person, and fill in the form with the right values.
with the normal dropdown I could just do :

```
$('#Relation').val('Customer')
```

And it would select a value in the dropdown with the value John.
If this doesn't exist it wouldn't do anything.

Now that i am using this plugin, this doesn't work anymore.
The DOM code is : (this code is for selecting a relation)

```
 <div class="combobox-container"> 
<input name="Visitor.Relation" type="hidden" value=""> 
<div class="input-group"> 
<input tabindex="5" class="form-control combobox" type="text" placeholder="-- Selecteer een relatie --" autocomplete="off"> <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </span> 
</div> 
</div>
```